# TS Compiler API, how to print out fully reduced intersection type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I have this code:

```
type Foo = { foo?: string };

type Bar = { bar?: string };

type FooBar = Required<Foo> & Bar;
```

And I am printing out the reduced type with the Typescript Compiler API like so:

```
const stmt = sourceFile.statements[2] as ts.TypeAliasDeclaration;

const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(stmt.type)

const str = typeChecker.typeToString(type, undefined, ts.TypeFormatFlags.NoTruncation | ts.TypeFormatFlags.InTypeAlias)

console.log(str)
```

The type I expect to see logged is `{ foo: string, bar?: string }`, but I instead get `Required<Foo> & Bar`.

If I change FooBar to `FooBar = Required<Foo>`, then the proper type is logged : `{ foo: string }`

So it seems to be an issue with intersection types, does anyone know how I can fully reduce them?

EDIT: I was able to find a somewhat hacky solution by wrapping FooBar in a recursive widening type utility that looks like this:

```
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object ? T extends infer O ? {
    [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]>;
} : never : T;
```

I inject this into the source file when creating the program and then use [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/) to update the type alias declaration node. Here's a minimal example:

```
const node = sourceFile.getTypeAlias('FooBar')
const { type } = node.getStructure()
node.set({ type: `___ExpandRecursively<${type}>` })
const ty = node.getType().compilerType

// Yields reduced type: `{ foo: string; bar?: string; }`
console.log(checker.typeToString(ty, undefined, ts.TypeFormatFlags.NoTruncation | ts.TypeFormatFlags.InTypeAlias))
```

I would love to hear from anyone that has a more elegant solution